# How does report visual filter work when filter direction is opposite?

Tags: powerbi

[image]

1st image shows the model and filter direction.

2nd image shows 3 table visual.

3rd image shows the effect of clicking on account id 11 from the account table causing the filter of the other table visuals.

Image 4 shows the selection of account id 11 in the transaction table. This does not filter the account table since the filter direction is opposite. However, why does it filter the other table (top) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filters propagate "downstream" in the direction of relationships.

`Account` filters `Transaction` but
`Transaction` does not filter `Account`.

In the top table, your row headers are from `Account` but your `Amount` measure is from `Transaction`. Filtering `Transaction[Account ID]` does not filter the `Account` table but it does filter the `Transaction` table so that the measure returns a blank when it's asked to sum e.g. Markus's amount (since that's not his ID).

Blank results lead to those rows being suppressed. If you added `+ 0` to your measure to return zero rather than blank, you should still see all the names in the second scenario.

Comment: By second scenario do you refer to the last image and top tavle?

Comment: Yes, the case where you've selected `Transactions[Account ID] = 11`.